# How to tie a data model to multiple groups of radio buttons?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to present to the user a list of yes/no type questions. Here are my models:

```
 class QuestionModel {
    public String ID {get; set;}
    public String Title {get; set; }
    public bool Value {get; set; }
 }

 class QuestionsModel {
    List<QuestionModel> Questions {get; set}
 }
```

In my Razor code, I might be able to do something like:

```
 @foreach(var item in Model.Questions) {
       @Html.Label(item.Title);
       @Html.RadioButton(item.ID, "Yes");
       @Html.RadioButton(item.ID, "No");
  }
```

However, I don't see how the Value field in QuestionModel will get populated based on what the user has selected. Please help. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to use a `for` loop or an `EditorTemplate` for generating a collection otherwise the controls will not be named correctly and cannot be bound on post back

```
@model QuestionsModel
@(using Html.BeginForm())
{
  for (int i = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count; i++)
  {
    string yes = i + "Yes"; 
    string no = i + "No";
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Questions[i].ID)
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Questions[i].Title) // assuming you don't want to edit this
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Questions[i].Value, true, new { id = @yes })
    <label for="@yes">Yes</label>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Questions[i].Value, false, new { id = @no })
    <label for="@no">No</label>
  }
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```